# Mailing only delivering to some contacts

Tags: contacts, email, mailing

When I send a mailing out it is only being delivered to I think around 50% of the contacts it should be. I am not receiving them despite being on the mailing list and others I have asked. However, when I click on the report it is saying it has successfully delivered to all contacts. I assume it is around 50% as my clicks are down 50% compared to 2 weeks ago.

Comment: can you compare before and after and see if it particular mailing platforms that are affected

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you use a DKIM-signature and have a valid SPF-entry on your host/server-side.